# Prove that $e^{f_1} + e^{f_2} \equiv 1$ is impossible

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: Let $f_1, f_2$ be two entire functions not constant. Prove that $e^{f_1} + e^{f_2} \equiv 1$ is impossible.

I tried to apply the Picard's theorem to investigate the left side of $e^{f_1} + e^{f_2} \equiv 1$, but fail to gain any progress. If we try to represent $f_1$ or $f_2$ by the other one, the multiplicity is inevitable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex Analysis, Entire functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300552/complex-analysis-entire-functions) (found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24e%5Ef%2Be%5Eg%3D1%24%2C%20AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com&p=1))